# How To Apply Error Handling To Sub Shells

Tags: shell, error-handling, subshell

script1

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e

VALUE="`exit 1`"
echo "$VALUE" ok
```

script2

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e

echo "`exit 1`" && echo ok
```

Looks like pretty the same logic

Still the first script fails

```bash
./script1; echo $?
```

prints

```bash
1
```

while the second one doesn't

```bash
./script2; echo $?
```

prints

```bash
ok
0
```

So what is the difference here?

Is it matter of nested sub shell?

How to make `set -e` to affect all the nested down sub shells?

Or how to make the second script to fail on substitution invocation error with no computation flow even turned to `echo ok` at all?

Thank you

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises) (and https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/, and https://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling ). The short form is that `set -e` is an unusably broken-by-design misadventure, and the _safe_ way to write shell scripts is with explicit error handling (`foo || return` / `foo || exit`, _explicitly_, every time).